# Is there a way to document the functions returned by higher order functions in R?

Tags: r, roxygen2

Here is an example. Is there a way to get documentation for `add5()` ?

```
build_adder <- function(integer){
  out <- function(x){
    x+integer
  } 
}
add5 <- build_adder(5)
?add5
```

Comment: Since it's user defined not really.  To some extent: `args(add5); formals(add5)`